# CMake: Access variables across sub directories

Tags: cmake

I have a two sub directories from root on which one has the line:

```
 set(${LIBNAME}_publicheaders
     LocalizeResource.h
 )
```

I want to be able to access this variable from the other subdirectory. How can I do this?

Comment: I am trying to use: 
get_directory_property (${VAR} DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/abc" DEFINITION "${LIB_NAME}_publicheaders")

but I am not sure if my syntax is correct

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@JoakimGebart's answer is probably the more common way to go about this.  However, you *can* also use [`get_directory_property`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command:get_directory_property) directly from within the second subdir to achieve what you're after.

I see that in your comment, you've used `${LIB_NAME}_publicheaders`, but in your question you have `${LIBNAME}_publicheaders`.  This could be the cause of your problems, since the command should work like this:

```
get_directory_property(MyVar
    DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/abc
    DEFINITION ${LIBNAME}_publicheaders)
```

However, there are a couple of provisos:

1. This has to be called *after* setting the variable in the subdir.  i.e. you'd have to ensure `add_subdirectory(abc)` was called before the `add_subdirectory` for the one where this will be used.
2. If `LIBNAME` is also `set` inside the same subdir (abc), you'll need to retrieve the value for that first.

So, while this is probably a less common solution, it has the advantage that it doesn't "pollute" the global namespace with subdir-specific variables - this works from with a subdir referring to another subdir.

Answer (score 4):

You can set the variable in the parent scope using the `PARENT_SCOPE` option to set()

Example:

```
set(${LIBNAME}_publicheaders
    LocalizeResource.h
    PARENT_SCOPE
)
```

See http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command:set

This, however, means that the variable is available not only in the other subdirectory, but in any other subdirectories on the same level as well.

Comment: I read that I can use get_directory_property to get the variable. Do you know if this is true?

Comment: I believe the variable should just get passed along to the subdirectories without any get_directory_property call, so you should be able to write `${mylib_publicheaders}` in the other subdirectory to get the list of headers you set.

Comment: But isn't that only in the case of root. I have the variable set in a subdirectory. I tried and it give me blank

Comment: I just tried it with two subdirectories. It depends on the order of the `add_subdirectory`-calls, if I do the `set(... PARENT_SCOPE)` in dir1, and `add_subdirectory(dir1)` first, then `add_subdirectory(dir2)`, I get the value in dir2. If I do it the other way around, `add_subdirectory(dir2)`, then `add_subdirectory(dir1)`, the value has not yet been set when I enter dir2.

Comment: +1 since I think this is the most common way of handling the issue.